# C++ SSL/HTTPS 301 redirect loop

Tags: c++, loops, ssl

Trying to make this short.

Im trying to write a small tool that can interact with encrypted connections (HTTPS using SSL -> OpenSSL). I do this on a Mac.

This is how i connect:

```
BIO * SSL_Connect(std::string host_IPv4, std::string truststore){

SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();

SSL * ssl;
BIO * bio;
SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

std::string host = host_IPv4 + ":443";

if(ctx == NULL){

    //std::cout << ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()) << std::endl;

}

int load_error = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, truststore.c_str(), NULL);

if(load_error == 0){

    //std::cout << "ERROR loading TrustedStore" << std::endl;

}
else{

    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, host.c_str());

    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0){

        //std::cout << "Connection failed!" << std::endl;

    }
    else{

        if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK){

            //std::cout << "Fatal Cert Error!" << std::endl;

        }
        else{

            //std::cout << "SSL Connection established!!!" << std::endl;

        }

    }

}

return bio;

}
```

My code does work, my problem is the following:

I try to connect to eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/something
Then i get a 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' response from server pointing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/something (exact the same URL)

And this goes on forever.. Can someone explain why this is happening? I cant seem to find anything similar on google :/

If you need additional information i can provide them.

HTTP Code:

```
http_get_header create_http_get_header(std::string url, std::string cookie, int mode){

http_get_header header;

std::vector<std::string> UA = populate_user_agents();

int random_value;

//parse url, need format: www.xxxx.yyy/zzzzzz
if(url.substr(0, 5) == "https"){ //https://www.google.com / https://google.com

    if(url.substr(0, 11) == "https://www"){ //https://www.google.de

        url = url.substr(8, url.length());

    }
    else{ //https://google.com

        url = url.substr(8, url.length());
        url = "www." + url;

    }

}
else if(url.substr(0, 5) == "http:"){ //http://www.google.com / http://google.com

    if(url.substr(0, 10) == "http://www"){ //http://www.google.com

        url = url.substr(7, url.length());

    }
    else{ //http://google.com

        url = url.substr(7, url.length());
        url = "www." + url;

    }

}
else if(url.substr(0, 4) == "www."){ //www.google.com

    //nothing todo

}
else{ //google.com

    url = "www." + url;

}

//check for at least one '/', if none (www.google.com) append one
if(!(url.find("/")<1800000)){

    url = url + "/";

}

//check if we can last the www. at the beginning
if(mode == 1){

    url = url.substr(4, url.length());

}

header.Host = "Host: " + url.substr(0, url.find("/"));
header.GET = "GET " + url.substr(url.find("/"), url.length()) + " HTTP/1.1";

srand(time(NULL));
random_value = rand() % 16 + 1;

header.UserAgent = "User-Agent: " + UA[random_value-1];
header.Acc = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
header.AccLang = "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
header.AccEncoding = "";

//Check for Cookie
if(cookie == ""){

    header.Cookie = "";

}
else{

    header.Cookie = "Cookie: " + cookie;

}

header.Connection = "Connection: close";

return header;

}
```

This is just how i create the HTTP header.. i do not retry to get the new url pointed by 'Location:', i just saw the response pointing to the exact same url and was wondering why..

I request:

```
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuchen
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuchen
```

its the same, not something with the spelling..

Comment: Whatever the cause of the problem is, it has nothing to do with the code you have shown here. You just show the TLS setup and not the HTTP part inside the TLS connection.

Comment: I am prretty sure what you get is a different URL. Likely ending with '/'.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to connect to eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/something Then i get a 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' response from server pointing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/something (exact the same URL)

It is NOT the same URL.  Look more closely at the `Location` header during the redirect.

A request to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/something` gets redirected to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something`. Note the difference in cases.  A request to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something` returns actual content, not another redirect.

So, if you are stuck in a redirect loop, you are not requesting the redirected URL correctly.  But you did not show your HTTP code.

**Update**: as you noted, you are not setting up the `Host` header correctly.  And the reason for that is because you are not parsing the URL's hostname correctly to begin with.  In particular, you are adding/removing `www` when you should not be.  That is part of the hostname, and is important for proper DNS lookups and `Host` header assignment.

Try something more like this instead (see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for the formal definition of URL syntax):

```
http_get_header create_http_get_header(std::string url, std::string cookie, int mode)
{
    http_get_header header;

    std::vector<std::string> UA = populate_user_agents();

    int random_value;

    //parse url

    //std::string scheme;
    std::string host;
    std::string port;
    std::string path;
    std::string query;
    //std::string fragment;

    std::string::size_type n = url.find(":");
    if (n != std::string::npos)
    {
        //scheme = url.substr(0, n);
        url = url.substr(n+1);
    }

    if (url.substr(0, 2) == "//")
    {
        n = url.find_first_of("/?#", 2);
        if (n != std::string::npos)
        {
            host = url.substr(2, n-2);

            if (url[n] == '/')
            {
                path = url.substr(n);

                n = path.find_first_of("?#");
                if (n != std::string::npos)
                {
                    std::string tmp = path.substr(n);
                    path = path.substr(0, n-1);

                    if (tmp[0] == '?')
                    {
                        query = tmp.substr(1);

                        n = query.find("#");
                        if (n != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            //fragment = query.substr(n+1);
                            query = query.substr(0, n-1);
                        }
                    }
                    /*else
                        fragment = tmp.substr(1);*/
                }
            }
            else if (url[n] == '?')
            {
                query = url.substr(n+1);

                n = query.find("#");
                if (n != std::string::npos)
                {
                    //fragment = query.substr(n+1);
                    query = query.substr(0, n-1);
                }
            }
            /*else
                fragment = url.substr(n+1);*/
        }
        else
            host = url;

        n = host.rfind("@");
        if (n != std::string::npos)
            host = host.substr(n+1);

        n = host.find(":");
        if (n != std::string::npos)
        {
            port = host.substr(n+1);
            host = host.substr(0, n-1);
        }
    }

    if (path == "")
        path = "/";

    header.Host = "Host: " + host;
    if (port != "") header.Host += (":" + port);

    header.GET = "GET " + path;
    if (query != "") header.GET += ("?" + query);
    header.GET += " HTTP/1.1";

    srand(time(NULL));
    random_value = rand() % 16 + 1;

    header.UserAgent = "User-Agent: " + UA[random_value-1];
    header.Acc = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    header.AccLang = "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
    header.AccEncoding = "";

    //Check for Cookie
    if (cookie != "")
        header.Cookie = "Cookie: " + cookie;
    else
        header.Cookie = "";

    header.Connection = "Connection: close";

    return header;
}
```

Comment: i updated my question with the http code.. and sadly its not the thing with s -> S

Comment: Why are you doing special handling to add/strip `www` to/from the domain name?  Don't do that. A service provider might host multiple services on the same physical machine, so the `www` is important during DNS lookups. If you request `http://domain.com` and the server wants you to request `http://www.domain.com` instead, it will redirect you accordingly. Same with `http://www.domain.com` redirecting to `http://domain.com`. Let it. That is for the server to decide, not you.

Comment: All you need to worry about on your end is that everything after `http(s)://` (not counting a username/password before the domain), up to the first `/`, `?`, or `#` character, is the hostname. **Use it as-is**.

Comment: `if(!(url.find("/")<1800000))` is also wrong, should be `if(url.find("/") == std::string::npos)` instead. And URLs are not required to have a `/` after the hostname, so don't force it. If the server wants it, let it redirect accordingly.

Comment: You have not shown most of your real HTTP code. You have only shown the code that prepares the HTTP request header, but not the code that actually sends the request, or what the actual transmitted HTTP request looks like on the wire (maybe the request is malformed), or the code that reads the response, or the code that processes the response and performs redirect logic (where your loop is occurring).

Comment: Besides, per the HTTP spec, the client should prevent endless redirect loops in the first place. Stop your loop if you encounter a duplicate URL, or have redirected a max number of times (the recommended value is 5).  Per [RFC 2616 Section 10.3 Redirection 3xx](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3): "*A client SHOULD detect infinite redirection loops ... Note: previous versions of this specification recommended a maximum of five redirections. Content developers should be aware that there might be clients that implement such a fixed limitation.*"

Comment: I did not run into a loop because i do not follow the redirect (automatically), i just noticed it and where curioused why it happened.. But i got the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem.. really wired. It was that my GET Header field 'Host:' was:

> Host: www.de.wikipedia.org

But it must be:

> Host: de.wikipedia.org

That solved it.. but thanks to all of you!

Comment: That is because you are not parsing the URL host correctly in the first place.